# Resetting the global origin in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a Unet application, where the server is responsible for spawning units, and the clients (obviously) see the units and their movements. Clients can spawn stuff via server commands, and typical interactions.

What i'm hoping to allow, however, is each client to redefine their global 'origin' point. So if i'm in the world and i see it in front of me, i'd like to be able to turn around and determine that "hey! that point over there is now the origin", and have all the components move to that new location (which should be handled automatically by the NetworkTransforms).

Does anyone know how i would be able to accomplish this? Or even implement some sort of NetworkTransformOffset script based off the network transform?

Comment: Can't you put everything under a GameObject e.g. `originAnchor` and than move that object?

Answer (score 0):

## Yes....

By moving everything by an amount equal to `-1 * new_origin` yourself.

Comment: Why -1 * new_origin?
This seems like a very forceful way of doing this... There is no networked way? or way to reset the origin?